# I can't complete a pull request in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

My colleague submitted a pull request on a repository. I made a recommendation on renaming a function but I clicked "Approve with recommendations". However, from here I cannot do anything. I cannot "Complete" the pull request. The Complete button remains disabled.

[image]

We made a team and we gave the team Project Contributors. WHat else do we need to do? I've used Github for years and I cannot figure out why Azure DevOps UI is so terrible.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any merge conflicts in the pull request? Make sure to resolve them first.

Also, make sure that your user is not part of any group that has a **Deny**-policy possible overriding your Project Contributor rights.

Lastly, check the branch policies ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies)) to see if anything is hindering you from completing the request.